# MySQL - I get only 1 row in my output?

Tags: java, mysql

This is my jsp page to execute a query. When I run it, I get only 1 row from the courses table in the output. I was getting the right output a while ago, then I started working with the interface and realised that I don't get the correct output anymore.
Can anybody point out the mistake? Thank you.

```
rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from courses");

<TABLE cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
<%

while (rs.next()) {
%>
<TR>
<TD><%=rs.getString(1)%></TD>
<TD><%=rs.getString(2)%></TD>
<TD><%=rs.getString(3)%></TD>
<TD><%=rs.getString(4)%></TD>
<TD><%=rs.getString(5)%></TD>
<TD><%=rs.getString(6)%></TD>
<TD><%=rs.getString(7)%></TD>
</TR>
}
```

Comment: How many records are in the courses table? Make sure that it's more than one.

Comment: ya obviously, there are more than 100

Comment: you may attach the name of the programming language used as a tag

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your paste is correct you are missing the

```
<%
}
%>
```

around the end of the loop.

Comment: everything was right, i just restarted the tomcat server and it worked fine. thanks